# How to syncronise Jenkins stages on different nodes to single changeset?

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I have a Jenkins pipeline that runs two jobs on different slaves as follows

```
node('node-1') {
    stage ('Checkout') {
        checkout scm
    }
    stage ('Build First Part') {
        < do some building >
    }
}
node('node-2') {
    stage ('Checkout') {
        checkout scm
    }     
    stage ('Build Second Part') {
        < do some more building >
    }
}
```

The task on node-2 requires the task on node-1 to complete first.

I've noticed that if a commit occurs while the task on node-1 is running that the checkout on node-2 contains the new commit.

I'm using Perforce for source control.

How do I ensure that the checkouts on the two nodes are on the same changeset?

Comment: Use a label. Read up on `p4 tag`.

Comment: @BryanPendleton How do you specify which tag to checkout?

Comment: Do you check out the same sources (same clientview) on both nodes?

Comment: @pitseeker Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the checkout on the master (or anywhere else) and stash it.
Then unstash it on each node. It is actually quicker than you might assume.

For example:

```
node() {
  stage ('Checkout') {
    checkout scm
    stash name: 'checkout'
  }
}

builders['builder1'] = {
  node('node-1'){
    stage('Build First Part') {
      cleanWs()
      unstash 'checkout'
      < do some building >
    }
  }
}
builders['builder2'] = {
  node('node-2'){
    stage('Build Second Part') {
      cleanWs()
      unstash 'checkout'
      < do some more building >
    }
  }
}
parallel builders
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @pitseekers answer you can achieve this by

On the first build node:

- Save the changeset to a file (p4_changelist.txt)
- Stash the saved file.

Then on the second build node:

- Unstash the file
- Read the changelist value out of the file to a variable.
- Checkout the repository using the changelist value. This is the **pin** argument in the perforce populate list.

Pipeline steps:

```
node('node-1') {
    stage ('Checkout') {
        checkout scm
    }
    stage ('Save changelist number') {
        writeFile file: 'p4_changelist.txt', text: "${env.P4_CHANGELIST}"
        stash includes: 'p4_changelist.txt', name: 'p4_changelist'
    }
    stage ('Build First Part') {
        < do some building >
    }
} 
node('node-2') {
    stage ('Checkout') {
        unstash 'p4_changelist'
        def changelist = readFile 'p4_changelist.txt'
        checkout perforce(
            credential: 'credential',
            populate: autoClean(
                delete: true,
                modtime: false,
                parallel: [
                    enable: false,
                    minbytes: '1024',
                    minfiles: '1',
                    threads: '4'
                ],
                // ****** Use the read changelist value here ******
                pin: changelist,
                quiet: true,
                replace: true,
                tidy: false
            ),
            workspace: manualSpec(
                charset: 'none',
                name: 'jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}-${EXECUTOR_NUMBER}',
                pinHost: false,
                spec: clientSpec(
                    allwrite: false,
                    backup: false,
                    clobber: true,
                    compress: false,
                    line: 'LOCAL',
                    locked: false,
                    modtime: false,
                    rmdir: false,
                    serverID: '',
                    streamName: '',
                    type: 'WRITABLE',
                    view: ''
                )
            )
        )
    }      
    stage ('Build Second Part') {
        < do some more building >
    }
}
```